# Problema para gerar relatorios com DOMPDF + Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, relatório, dompdf

Ola,

Estou tentando gerar um relatório utilizando Dompdf porem estou encontrando o seguinte erro

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Relatorio::$dompdf

Filename: controllers/Relatorio.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_ads\application\controllers\Relatorio.php
Line: 24
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_ads\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Minha view:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

    body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    table thead tr th td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    }

    table thead tr th {
    background-color: #bac6cb;
    font-size: 17px;
    }

    table tbody tr td {
    background-color: #9ba7ac;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="flex-box">
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center" colspan="2"><h2>Alunos com maior número de locação</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center">
    <th>Nome do aluno</th>
    <th>Quantidade de locação</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rel as $linha) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td style=\"text-align: center\">" . $linha['nome'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style=\"text-align: center\">" . $linha['count'] . "</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
    Relatório de alunos que mais locaram E-Book &reg;
   </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Meu Controller

class Relatorio extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('relatorio_model');
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('relatorio/index');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}



public function geraRelatorio() {
    $dados = $this->input->post();
    if ($dados['tipo_relatorio'] == 'REL_LIVRO_MAIS_LOCADO') {
         $data['rel'] = $this->relatorio_model->queryAlunosMaisLocaram();
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $html = $this->load->view('relatorio/livros_mais_locados', $dados, true);
        $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
        $this->dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait"); // to change page orientation to landscape, change the parameter “portrait” to “landscape”
        $this->dompdf->render();
        $filename = "mypdf.pdf";
        $this->dompdf->stream($filename); // to Download PDF
    }
    if ($dados['tipo_relatorio'] == 'REL_ALUNOS_MAIS_LOCARAM') {
        $data['rel'] = $this->relatorio_model->queryAlunosMaisLocaram();
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $html = $this->load->view('relatorio/alunos_mais_locaram', $dados, true);
        $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
        $this->dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait"); // to change page orientation to landscape, change the parameter “portrait” to “landscape”
        $this->dompdf->render();
        $filename = "mypdf.pdf";
        $this->dompdf->stream($filename); // to Download PDF
    }
}
}
```

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Pra começar, eu recomendaria uma biblioteca mais versátil e menos complicada, como a [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf). Mas se você quer mesmo continuar usando essa aí, ao menos procure a versão mais atual: [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

Esse erro quer dizer que a classe `Relatorio` não tem a propriedade `$dompdf` que você está invocando. Isso ocorre por causa da maneira como vc está carregando a biblioteca no `CodeIgniter`. Antes de usar uma biblioteca externa no `CodeIgniter` leia [isso aqui](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=extending) com atenção.

Ciente dessas especificações, uma das maneiras corretas de se fazer isso seria declarando a `dompdf`como uma biblioteca em `/application/libraries/PdfCreator.php`:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class PdfCreator {

    public function __construct() {
        require_once('/usr/share/php/dompdf/vendor/autoload.php');
        $this->dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
    }

}
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->PdfCreator = new PdfCreator();
```

Declarada a biblioteca, carrega-se na instância (eu prefiro [autoload](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload) `/application/config/autoload.php`). No caso, vc vai carregá-la em `libraries`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
    'PdfCreator'
);
```

Outra coisa que vc precisa entender é que a `dompdf` não vai renderizar o `$html` da forma que vc está fazendo porque o método `$this->load->view()` retorna um `object`, e não uma `string`. Mas dá pra corrigir isso usando a propriedade correta do objeto retornado, que é `final_output`. No seu `controller`, o método que cria o `pdf` fica assim:

```
function geraRelatorio(){
    $dompdf = $this->PdfCreator->dompdf;
    $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $data['rel'] = [0=>['nome'=>'teste','count'=>'2']];
    $view = $this->load->view('pages/dompdf',$data);
    $html = $view->output->final_output;
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
}
```

Mais: você está criando `$data['rel']` mas está passando apenas `$dados` para a `view`. No entanto, a sua `view` faz um `foreach` no `array` `$rel`. Cuidado com isso, ou vc vai ter outro problema na hora de gerar o documento, pois o programa vai procurar por uma variável `$rel` que não existe no escopo dele.

Mais: `dompdf` tem sérios problemas para renderizar `html` mal formado, **[e o próprio desenvolvedor é que fala isso](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#limitations-known-issues)**. Portanto, qualquer erro na hora de declarar elementos vai gerar falhas "inesperadas". Digo isso porque na sua `view` você está declarando o `<style>` no corpo do documento `html`, e isso vai te dar dor de cabeça ao usar essa biblioteca. Tentei evitar isso com `$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);`, mas parece que não foi suficiente.

Eu fiz uma `view` assim que funcionou:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="../assets/dompdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flex-box">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center" colspan="2"><h2>Alunos com maior número de locação</h2></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align: center">
                        <th>Nome do aluno</th>
                        <th>Quantidade de locação</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($rel as $linha) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo "<td style=\"text-align: center\">" . $linha['nome'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td style=\"text-align: center\">" . $linha['count'] . "</td>";
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>
                Relatório de alunos que mais locaram E-Book &reg;
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

É isso.

Comment: A biblioteca mPDF é bem complicada e pouco usual, recomendo fortemente a biblioteca PHPJasper:

https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper

Comment: Significa que funciona muito bem até certo limite de dados, por exemplo: relatórios muito grandes com vários joins, é preciso escrever muito pra gerar, e isso demanda tempo, embora seja muito bom em pequenos e médios relatórios, pouco usual pq você precisa escrever muito pra gerar um relatório de médio a grande porte.

Comment: Exatamente por isso que escrevi como comentário(sugestão ou dica) e não como resposta ;)

Comment: O importante é a solução funcionar bem para o colega que perguntou, espero que seja o caso.